# Do you have to get Drive permission in a Google Chrome Extension in order to call the Drive API?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

My Extension has the following permissions called out in the Manifest:

```
"oauth2": {
        "client_id": "425460661917-smaehlat7c66p1ns6t90ssj3jmlrrecm.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "scopes": [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"
      ]
  },
```

I only want to use Google Drive when a user explicitly grants permission. I am only interested in file metadata at this point, so when the user indicates it, I used an Ajax call to get the metadata:

```
$.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              beforeSend: function(request) {
                request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
              },
              url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + googleFileID + "?fields=sharingUser",
              dataType: 'json',
              processData: true,
              success: function(gDocsMeta2) {// then code...
```

This works great.

However, every user does not want to use my app with Drive, but (I think) because of the 'drive.readonly' in the manifest, understandably, Chrome periodically pops a permission request.

Is there a way to get more situational permission? With my existing code, when the user DOES request data from Drive a permission is popped...

Any help/direction appreciated.

Comment: What I can suggest is that first you should know which methods you'll be using. Some methods like [files.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create) require a full write permission like the "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive" scope. So, if you'll be using those kind of methods, include higher permissions.

Comment: I need file metadata read only. But that isn't the issue - the issue is that I only want to prompt the user for permission IF they open a Google Doc...not automatically at install of my Extension. In other words, I don't want to put the permission in the manifest, where it will apply universally. I want to make the permission an on-demand request.